# Apple Wallet serial numbering scheme

Tags: php, ios, wallet

I'm creating Apple Wallet passes and they are quite happy to install. The web services to update them are a little tricky though. One thing I'm running into is what strategy to use for generating serial numbers.

For any given user, there will only ever be one pass, but it may be installed on multiple devices. As far as I can see, this means that I could use a single static value for the serial number. What's more, I think I can use a single serial number across *all* users, because any requests that ask for a pass are accompanied by an authentication token, so if I have a passes table like this:

| Passes |
| --- |
| id |
| pass_type_id |
| serial |
| user_id |

it will have one row for each user, and the combination of `pass_type_id` and `user_id` will always be unique, so it really doesn't matter what `serial` is.

Does this seem reasonable? If not, what scheme should I use for creating serial numbers?

As a minor aside, is it reasonable to store the pass in the table directly as a blob, or should I generate them dynamically every time they are requested (which is somewhat slow with having to zip images etc)?